# Ngnix, Symfony2, SSL & wildcard subdomains redirection

Tags: redirect, ssl, nginx, wildcard

I’m looking for a specific Nginx configuration :

`www.mydomain.com` => `www.mydomain.com`
`dev.mydomain.com` => `dev.mydomain.com`
`user1.mydomain.com` => `www.mydomain.com/user/user1`
`user2.mydomain.com` => `www.mydomain.com/user/user2`
...

I have some requirements :

- The users pages don’t have to be redirected, the visible URL must keep the subdomain.
- Every URL must be available in HTTP, but with a 301 redirection to HTTPS

The project uses Symfony2.
Does anyone have some information for me?

Thanks :)